# <select> with two different options not from database, but custom text php mysql, html

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, dropdown

I have my database in phpmyadmin, and I have a table 'employees'. One of the fields is 'pay_item', and this particular field is type 'varchar(100)'.

I want to have a dropdown  in my php website, and I want it to have two different options: 'Hourly' and 'Salary'.

I have got it to retrieve the values from the DB, so whatever that employee has selected, it will come up no the screen, and that 'pay_item' will be selected on the dropdown.

The problem I have right now, is that when I submit my form, it is not sending the selected choice to the DB. Say I want to edit from one to the other, it won't take the change.

I know how to write  using a 'while' loop, and populate from the DB, but in this case, I just want to have these two options, and not use a while, since there is not a specific table for 'pay_items'

This is the code I have so far:

```
        <td colspan="3">
        <select name="pay_item">

            <?
                echo"   <option value=\"$pay_item\"";
            if($pay_item=="Regular Hourly")
                echo" selected";
                echo">Regular Hourly</option>\n";
            
                echo"   <option value=\"$pay_item\"";
            if($pay_item=="Regular Salary")
                echo" selected";
                echo">Regular Salary</option>\n";

            ?>
            </select>
        </td>
```

Now, I forgot to mention that when it is on 'Regular Salary', it DOES take the change to 'Regular Hourly', but not the other way around, so I assumed there must be something wrong with the structure of the .

Before, I had this as a textfield, so people were entering 'Regular Hourly' and so, but from time to time, they would enter grammatical errors, so I am trying to avoid that with a dropdown.

The way I am sending this to the DB, is with a normal UPDATE or INSERT query.

```
$db_link->query("INSERT INTO employees (pay_item) VALUES ('$pay_item')");

$db_link->query("UPDATE employees SET pay_item='$pay_item' WHERE id = '$user_id'");
```

In my Database, 'pay_item', is VARCHAR(100), since I used to have it as a textfield, and the only two values I would want there are 'Regular Hourly' and 'Regular Salary'. So I wanted to create a Drop Down where I can populate with those two options.

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: " it is not sending the selected choice to the DB" .. where is the code that is supposed to send the selected choice to DB?

Comment: It's just a normal UPDATE or INSERT query.....

$db_link->query("UPDATE employees SET pay_item='$pay_item'  WHERE id = '$user_id'");

and/or

$db_link->query("INSERT INTO employees (pay_item) VALUES ('$pay_item')");

I used to have people entering 'Regular Hourly' in a text field, so that was working fine, but I don't want people entering grammatical mistakes, so I thought a drop down would be a good choice to avoid this....but when changed, it doesn't work properly...

Comment: Update your question with all relevant code, including the part where you got information from the form and save into database

Comment: What's the value of `$pay_item` ? Update your question with ALL relevant code.

Comment: this code is vulnerable to **sql injection**, please use only **prepared statements with parameters** see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: sorry @FelippeDuarte, I am new to this, I'm trying to add as much code as I know, but thanks for this, I'll add that too....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if that is what you want

```
<td colspan="3">
    <select name="pay_item">

        <?php
        if($pay_item === "Regular Hourly"){
            echo "<option value='Regular Hourly' selected>Regular Hourly</option>";
            echo "<option value='Regular Salary'>Regular Salary</option>"
             }
         elseif($pay_item === "Regular Salary"){
             echo "<option value='Regular Salary' selected>Regular Salary</option>";
             echo "<option value='Regular Hourly'>Regular Hourly</option>";
             }
        

        ?>
        </select>
    </td>
```

Depending on the value of $pay_item the dropdown list will be generated

Comment: OMG! Let me tell you, I tried a lot of these variations, not sure why I missed this one, YES, that fixed everything, now it is selecting the right choice, and also accepting the changes/edits. Thanks a lot!!!